# TiKZ: Why is a line visible between 2 fitted nodes with inner/outer sep =0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf

Consider the snippet below (compiled with PDFLatex TexLive 2015).

Why is DocumentViewer (3.18.2, Ubuntu 16) displaying a thin line (some zoom levels)? I have set the outer/inner sep  to 0. Is this a flaw in PDF-rendering or has this TiKZ snippet an issue?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, fill=blue,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=5cm] (first) at (10,10) {};
\node[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, fill=blue,minimum width=5cm, fit=(first.north)(first.south),anchor=east] (second) at (first.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Modern rendering engines use antialiasing to get nice edges, but antialiasing doesn't work very well when the objects are touching on a non-pixel boundary.

Comment: Try to add the `line width=0,draw=blue` option to your nodes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the problem is rendering in viewer (I use Sumatra). If I magnify image obtained with your code, this line disappear. As cure for this viewers discrepancy try the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every node/.style =
      {fill=blue, draw=blue, % <-- added "draw"
       inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, 
       minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm
      }
    ]
  \node (first) at (10,10) {};
  \node[fit=(first.north) (first.south),anchor=east] (second) at (first.west) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In the Percusse answer is explanation why in your case a thin line between adjacent nodes is visible. Added option `draw` in above MWE cause, that nodes overlap for thickness of border lines:

[image]

consequently there is no more place for image viewer artifacts. Above picture is generated with:

```
\documentclass{book}\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
test/.style = {fill=#1, draw=#1, draw opacity=0.5,
               inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, 
               minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm}
                        ]
\node (first)  [test=blue]  {};
\node (second) [test=red,
                fit=(first.north) (first.south),
                anchor=east] at (first.west) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To get rectangles with the same sizes as the initial example, you may add the option `line width=0`.

Comment: I tested this, but result is not the same (as I expected). probably the problem is rendering in viewer (I use Sumatra). If I magnify image, this line disappear (the same happen with OP code).

Comment: Did you try `line width=0,draw=blue` or just `line width=0`?

Comment: I test with `every node/.style = {fill=blue, %draw=blue,
                     inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, 
                     minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm,
                     line width=0pt}`

Comment: With evince/DocumentViewer (Linux), my trick works. I try it with Sumatra (Windows) and the artifact remains visible at some zoom levels.

Answer (score 5):

This effect is generally known as the conflation artifact and it has nothing to do with TikZ. It is a well-known artifact by the graphic designers and they avoid this by avoiding shapes sharing perfectly aligned edges or shapes filling a cut-out exactly.

See for example rendering problems [here](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/projects/GanEtAl14/sample.html?contour) (wait a bit after you click to see the changes). Similarly graphics.SE has lots of relevant questions and probably the Hillary logo is the most voted one: [Is there a reason Hillary Clinton's logo has hidden notches?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches)

So the typical solution is to make things overlap slightly.

Comment: This is an interesting perspective (different from mine as someone who specialized in rendering on pixel diplays). Yes, the best approach is often a slight overlap.