# discrepancy between filled paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I superpose two `\path [fill=...]` that should match exactly, I get an outer lining from the first fill.

It doesn't appear to be a shortcoming of the pdf viewer, as it also shows once `convert`ed to `png`.

[image]

How to get around this ?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) ;
  \path [fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (1,1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a viewer issue and then carried over to rendered png. More here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331951/tikz-why-is-a-line-visible-between-2-fitted-nodes-with-inner-outer-sep-0