# QR code contains weird lines

Tags: qrcode

When using the `qrcode` package my QR codes have all of their pixels spread out causing lines to appear, see the image (hope it's visible).

How do I get rid of this? More importantly, will it be visible in print, or is it just in the PDF version?

```tex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}
\qrcode{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in another pdf viewer?

Comment: Yes, it appears in Evince, Zathura and Google Chrome (here it's even more prominent)

Comment: It looks fine in the build in viewer of texstudio as well as in adobe reader.

Comment: Then it should be a problem with my setup, but it appears in Overleaf too (both Chrome on Windows and Linux) https://www.overleaf.com/read/kxbdwdzmtwyv

Comment: It's not your setup, it is a viewer problem. Some pdf viewer do some trickery which they call "thin line enhancement" and similar.

Comment: You're right, Adobe Reader works well. Do you want  to post it as an answer?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331975/36296 for an already existing answer

Comment: If I try with my phone the QRcode in the image, I see “test”.

Comment: @egreg yes, the QR code is readable, I'm asking about this just from an aesthetic point of view

Comment: It works well with gv and okular, too.